# Led - Manual control of WS2801 chip

Tags: gpio, led

I'm wondering if there's a way to manually control a multicolour LED strip powered by a WS2801 chip, i.e. being able to type a bash command from raspbian or any kind of software control, something of the type :

```
light-control --enable 12
```

Where 12 is the number of the LED in the chain.

Thanks you :)

Comment: Only if the software you are using to control the LEDs provides such an interface.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to figure out, is there anything out there that can control this kind of chip with ease ?

Comment: Adafruit has [a C++ library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-WS2801-Library).  I dunno anything about it, it was just the first hit I got searching "WS2801 software".

Comment: @goldilocks I think the ws2801 is one of those chips with quite tight timing requirements.  You won't be able to use Linux timing, you'll need to use a DMA/PWM peripheral solution, or possibly a SPI peripheral solution on the Pi.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of adafruit stuff is for the arduino, although it can still be useful if you have that and the data sheet to consult.  Not an out-of-the-box solution, esp. if you need extra hardware.